# Remove JQuery validationEngine from form

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using [Position Absolute's jQuery validationEngine](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/) but I need to remove it after attaching it to a form.

I have 2 submit buttons on my form - one for save and one for save as draft.

I attach the validationEngine to the form when Save is clicked.  If the validation fails, and the user clicks Save as Draft (by passing the validation), the validation engine is still attached to the form from when they clicked "save".

What I want to do is:

- allow the user to attempt to save
- validation fails and error is displayed
- and allow them to click save as draft without any validation being performed

I tried the unbind function and it appears to work, but it breaks the submit on the button completely.  I just want to remove the validationEngine and allow everything else to work as it was.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a function to the bottom of the validationEngine javascript file:

```
disable : function(formobj) {
    $(formobj).unbind("submit");
    $(formobj).die("submit");
    $(formobj).bind("submit", function() {
        return true;
    });
    $(formobj).live("submit", function() {
        return true;
    });
}
```

You pass in the jQuery form element. You could, of course, do this outside the validationEngine javascript file, I just found it easier to lump everything together :-)

The important bit is that you use both unbind AND die.

Comment: Thanks - that worked for me. I'd just add that besides adding this code to the js file, you have to change the click event of the buttons you don't want validation. I.e. $('#btnBack%>').click(function () {
                $('form').validationEngine('disable', $('form'));
            });

Answer (score 2):

Create global Validator variable

var globalValidator = null

Perform your validator logoc----

Then reset as per your logic using

```
function clearValidatorErrors(){
    if(globalValidator != null){
        globalValidator.resetForm(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Where and what would I set globalValidator to?

Comment: set it at the time of vlidation check .. like this

globalValidator  = $("#formname").validate({});

-- clear form validation using clearValidatorErrors(); function

Comment: I don't understand how is this a solution to the problem. I.e. how will this disable the validation when clicking on the "Save as Draft" button?

Answer (score 1):

That library doesn't seem to have any support for unbinding at runtime (which is pretty poor design if you ask me).

Here is the code that binds the 'submit'.

```
$(this).bind("submit", function(caller){   // ON FORM SUBMIT, CONTROL AJAX FUNCTION IF SPECIFIED ON DOCUMENT READY
    $.validationEngine.onSubmitValid = true;
    $.validationEngine.settings = settings;
    if($.validationEngine.submitValidation(this,settings) == false){
        if($.validationEngine.submitForm(this,settings) == true) {return false;}
    }else{
        settings.failure && settings.failure(); 
        return false;
    }       
})
```

The problem is, if you have more than one submit event handler attached to that form, `.unbind('submit')` will kill all of the events you had bound.

Assuming that the event was the last to be bound, you might be able to strip only the last event handler attached to submit:

```
 var events = $("#myForm").data('events');
 alert(events.submit.length); // should tell you how many events are bound..
 events.submit.splice(events.submit.length - 1, 1); // strip the last event
```