# jQuery remove validationEngine at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, jquery-validation-engine

I'm using the validationEngine script to validate a form. I init it with:

```
$("#formid").validationEngine();
```

I do not really submit the form through a submit button. I use an anchor element with an `onclick` event which calls a `saveElement()` function. In this function I call:

```
$("#formid").validationEngine('validate');
```

which works just fine.

Right after that, I reset the fields (for example, the content of input fields to `""`) through which the fields which are required start showing errors.

To prevent those errors from occurring, I would like to remove the validationEngine from the form element. But I just can't remove it. I tried various options, including the ones below, but none of them worked.

```
$('#formid').validationEngine('hideAll'); // To hide the error messages
$('#formid').validationEngine('detach');  // To remove the validationEngine
```

Does anyone have a suggestion how I can remove the validationEngine?

**Workaround**

It really seams like there is no unbind method. I've added a issue into the github project. Maybe they will implement an unbind method:
https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine/issues/287

As a workaround I came up with the following solutions:
You could either:

- Use jQuery.clone() to copy the form without the events, remove the original form and add the validationEngine to the form again
- Remove the validation classes on the form elements, store them in an array and insert them again after resetting the form

**Still open**

Maybe there is a better solution or workaround. If you know one, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're really overengineering things. This may not be the answer you expected, but here is what I think you should do:

Firstly, on the anchor element to submit, do this :

```
$('#anchorElement').click(function() {
    $('#formid').submit()
})
```

Then, you can do it like this to remove the form after submitting it:

```
$('#formid').submit(function() {
    // Do your submitting stuff, like validating.
    $(this).remove()
    // Or use $(this).hide() if you simply want to hide it.
})
```

But I wouldn't advocate the method of using an anchor element. Nicely degrading is a must for almost every website.

The problem is, when your user won't have javascript enabled, your form will never be submitted.

Btw, it looks like there is no "unbinding" of validationengine. See here for a solution: [Remove JQuery validationEngine from form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284986/remove-jquery-validationengine-from-form)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. I don't realy submit the form, but send the data through a ajax request to the server.
And I can't remove the form because I use the same form for editing all elements. And whether I hide it or slideUp (which I use) the errors are still shown. They are just shown over an empty background.

Comment: I wouldn't advocate your use, then (neither my solution, actually). Nicely degrading javascript is a must for almost every website.

Comment: What's the difference of using an anchor element instead of a submit element for this purpose? I can't belive, that you have to destroy the form element to remove the validationEngine when your sending your data through a AJAX request. Isn't there another way?

Comment: Of course it will never be submitted, but I'm developing an application there and not a normal website. Javascript is a requirement whithout the use just won't be able to use it. I searched the stackoverflow, and found this answer. But they didn't had the solution for my problem. And they use a submit and send it through submit which is different in my version.

Comment: Well, that's why I said "for almost every website" :-) You can use my trick to still use the submit part, though.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is still not fixed. I needed to disable validation in an existing app to allow postback events to take place without validating the form. I successfully did so by removing the validation classes with a regular expression like this:

```
// Work around
$('[class*="validate"]').each(function () {
      var _this = $(this);
      _this.attr("class", _this.attr("class").replace(/validate\[.*]+\s?/, ""));
});
```